# tm_bubbles from tmap disorganizes names when handling NAs

Tags: r, tmap

everyone. This is my first post. I am making a map of Ecuador showing the number of coronavirus confirmed cases by Province. This is the data I prepared. It has the province names and cases as for today. It has some NAs because not all provinces have confirmed cases. [covid19_confirmed_today](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S29NQ.png)

When I map the data. Everything looks, but when rolling over the bubbles, they do not show the correct name of the province. Only for the first three provinces which do not have NAs. I tried changing the NAs into zeros, but then small bubbles appear for the provinces which have zero confirmed cases. I don't want any bubbles for provinces that do not have confirmed cases.

```
covid19_confirmed_today_map <- covid19_confirmed_today %>%
  tm_shape() + tm_polygons(col = "skyblue", alpha = 0.2) +
  tm_bubbles(size = "Casos", col = "red", alpha = 0.6, border.lwd = NA)

covid19_confirmed_today_map <- tmap_leaflet(covid19_confirmed_today_map)
covid19_confirmed_today_map %>% removeLayersControl() %>%
  setView(lng = -78.50374, lat = -1.289527, zoom = 7) %>% fitBounds(-80.8, -4.2, -76.5, 0.8)
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9Aix.jpg), where it say "Carchi", it should say "Chimborazo". It says "Carchi" because that't the first province with NA. Whenerever there is a province with NA, it jumps to the next province and adds the name to that province (without NA) to the previous province (the one that had NA). Thank you very much for any help give.

Comment: I uploaded the interactive map to my website. You can better understand what I refer to https://elquantificador.org/post/salud/mapa-del-coronavirus-en-ecuador/

Comment: Yes, here they are. The shapefiles, the cvs data, and the markdown file with all the code. Thank you very much. https://github.com/aquijanoruiz/stackoverflow_questions/tree/master/t_map_coronavirus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider removing areas that have missing data from `covid19_confirmed_today`. Then add second `tm_shape` with this modified object before using `tm_bubbles`.

```
covid19nomissing <- covid19_confirmed_today[!is.na(covid19_confirmed_today$Casos) ,]

covid19_confirmed_today_map <- covid19_confirmed_today %>%
  tm_shape() + tm_polygons(col = "skyblue", alpha = 0.2) +
  tm_shape(covid19nomissing) +
  tm_bubbles(size = "Casos", col = "red", alpha = 0.6, border.lwd = NA)
```